# Can we omit 'depending on' in 'depending on whether'?

Tags: conjunctions, phrasal-verbs

In this sentence:

> The price varies, depending on whether you book by telephone or over
>   the internet.

can we omit 'depending on' and just say

> The price varies, whether you book by telephone or over
>   the internet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want to mean that the booking price depends on the manner of booking, whether by phone or Internet. If this is so  you need to keep *depending on*.

If you don't include *depending on* in your sentence, it means

There are various prices, and this is true (these various prices are there) whether you book by phone or internet. It does not matter how you book; expect varying prices either way.